# Measuring wow and flutter of a phonographic turntable with digital equipment

Tags: digital-logic, measurement

The old school way to measure: 3000 or 3150 kHz test tone from test record played back through phono cartridge/preamp into wow/flutter/drift meter and for turntable that has an electronic adjustment to optimize wow and flutter/rotational speed stability, adjust for minimum needle deflection on analog meters.

With DSOs and FFT analysers is there a more accurate way?

Comment: Why not just use a digital frequency meter with the test tone?

Comment: That would work if it could record min and max frequencies with rapid measurements. Does that exist?

Comment: What does "rapid measurements" mean to you? Many frequency meters can be connected to computers for data analysis. Actually, you could probably program an Arduino to do whatever you want at these low frequencies.

Comment: Do you know what a "wow/flutter/drift meter" does internally? Is there any reason you can't emulate those functions digitally? As it stands, this question is awfully broad.

Comment: To resolve 1 Hertz wow, you'll need at least 1 second time record and probably 5 or 10 seconds. Will your scope do that? And can your scope zoom into the spectrum, to resolve 1Hz? And does the scope's "mask" --- the preFFT time shaping--- support the resolution of tones that are not exactly an integer multiple of the time-window?

Comment: Wow and flutter are both frequency variations due to rotational speed variations. Flutter is fast variations. Wow is slow variations. Wow could be bad on cheap idler-wheel turn-tables, not usually an issue with better turn-tables. A good spectrum analyzer could probably measure wow and flutter. The analyzer in a low-cost scope, probably wouldn’t have enough resolution.

Comment: I always thought that wow and flutter measurements just told you how good the system was. I can't think of any way of adjusting for correction other than replacing or re-machining drive components such as drive wheels and pulleys and belts.

Answer (score 1):

Wow and flutter is a phenomenon of frequency modulation. Human ear is sensitive to instantaneous frequency deviation in the range of 0.1Hz ~ 200Hz. The frequency deviation from the carrier frequency can be shown on a FFT analyzer, provided that the FFT frequency resolution, which is equal to SamplingRate/FFTSize, is enough. Quantitative measurement of wow and flutter requires FM demodulation (see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344437920_Wow_and_Flutter_Measurement_using_Multi-Instrument)

A frequency meter measures the average frequency not the instantaneous one and thus is not able to reveal the wow and flutter. It can only measure the frequency drift.

Comment: This is closer to being a correct answer.  Really all one needs is the reference record and a sampler of trustworthy stability (eg a good soundcard); the rest is just software.

Answer (score 0):

Digital oscilloscopes likely employ crystal oscillators for their time-base frequency source. My rather ordinary DSO spec's the horizontal time-measuring scale **±50ppm over any ≥1ms time interval**. Good enough to do the turntable speed calibration for your ear. 100 part-per-million accuracy spec (or better) on the horizontal scale likely means that a crystal is used as the timing source.

A careful setup of triggering may be required. You should be able to see wow by adding *trigger holdoff*. Or simply slide the *horizontal position* to view the 3kHz signal some considerable time after the trigger point.

If you have an old-school oscilloscope with less-accurate time base that's not based on a crystal but you have an accurate source of 3 kHz signal (or some multiple or sub-multiple of 3 kHz), you can use the oscilloscope's **XY mode** to compare your accurate source against the turntable output signal, using *Lissajous figures*. Very accurate, perhaps too accurate to see large variations of speed or wow or flutter.

Comment: A scope isn't really suited to this sort of measurement; something like a sound card with a good sample clock would be far more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If the platter has strobe markings on it, maybe there’s a different way: use an optical sensor to pick up the pattern and feed that to your analysis system. Or, you could even make a disc with that pattern and apply that to the platter. Just a thought.

Bonus: a video from AnalogMagik describing their system, showing both optical and reference disc methods. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdbtXseqU2I